# Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised

Tags: python, flask

I am doing flask project and try to import data into indeed_extract.py and import into app.py
. When I was trying to run the project, it showed error.

`Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised.`

I checked `indeed_extract.py` and found that PyCharm gives me those messages:

```
Import "requests" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource
(module) requests
Import "bs4" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource
(module) bs4
```

I already have installed requests module and bs4 modules

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check if you're using the same python instance with the one declared in `environment variables`. Even if you installed the packages, they might be in a different place than the instance you're using to run the application

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu Thanks for your reply. How Can I check if am i using the same python instance?? Sorry for asking, I am a new in using virtual environment. 
ps. if you mean the interpreter, They are using the same interpreter

Comment: Yeah, I meant the interpreter. If they are using the same one, just check in the system's python folder if the libraries are there.

Comment: I make a virtual environment in "C:\Users\jjang\Documents\GitHub\flaskproject>"
But, those projects files in another folder (But, they are in same place). 
Do I have to move those on the virtual environment's folder??

Comment: If your project is somehwere else than the Vritual Environment then most liekly the interpreter where you isntalled the packages is not the same with the one used in the project

Comment: I am gonna move those files on the Virtual environment's folder and Run again restarting development tool now